# React setState empties old state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm running into a problem, looking for help.
I have a function called `mapRanks`. It gets called in `componentWillMount` and basically `setState` of elements using `map` through array of strings. It works fine with one array but I need to run it multiple times with multiple different arrays.

What happens is all the previous state becomes `array[0]` except the last one.

Please take a look at it:

```
export const mapRanks = (options, ranks, count, element) => {
  component = options.component;   // this component
  group = options.group;           // can be 'mapFirst', 'mapSecond', ...
  let col = count;
  let j = count;
  let k = count;

  const map = ranks.map((rank, i) => {
    if (i === col) {
      col = col + j--;
      if (j === 0) {
        j = k--;
      }
      return [element(i, group, rank), <div key={ i } className="clearfix"></div>];
    }
    return [element(i, group, rank)];
  });

  const newState = update(component.state, { maps: { [group]: { $set: map } } });
  component.setState(newState);

  setTimeout(() => { console.log(component.state.maps); }, 7000);
};
```

My state looks like this:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      maps: {
        mapFirst: [],
        mapSecond: [],
        mapThird: [],
        mapFourth: [],
      },
    };
  }
```

Also, I don't think it's related but I'm wondering... Do you see the `setTimeout` to `console.log` above? I had to use `setTimeout` because the state was returning `array[0]` but with `setTimeout`, it returns the whole array of elements. Why is that?

**EDIT: I think I found the problem.**

```
  componentWillMount() {
    mapRanks(
      { component: this, state: 'mapFirst' }, ranksFirst, 9, element
    );
    mapRanks(
      { component: this, state: 'mapSecond' }, ranksSecond, 8, element
    );
  }
```

When I add the second `mapRanks`, the both (two) `console.log` that returns has `mapFirst[0]` and `mapSecond[165]`.. I still don't understand why.

**2nd EDIT: I fixed it but...**

I added `setTimeout` for the second `mapRanks` function call and now it works. I need a better solution. Please help.

Comment: You had to use setTimeout because setState happens asynchronously, if you want to console log something after a setState you can pass a second parameter to setState which is a callback function that will execute after setState has been called, and then console log in that.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize setState is async. That explains it. I fixed it thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Rather than updating the state, diffing the DOM and rendering the changes each time you call [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate), React's going to try and batch the calls together and execute them before the next repaint, so that your code doesn't block the UI.

This means that [`setState` can be asynchronous](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2893-setstate-state-mutation-operation-may-be-synchronous-in-reactjs.htm), so you'll need to pass a callback function if you want to wait for the state to be changed before accessing it.

```
component.setState(newState, () => {
  console.log(component.state.maps);
});
```